# visual studio does not have System reference

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i'm using visual studio enterprise 15 on windows 10 on my pc.
in the classes i use system functions without the imports.
for example:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Xml
Imports WebControls

Public Class DataBaseTool

    Dim NRnd As New Random

end class
```

i use Random without System reference.
if i load my project on a my 2nd pc, with visual studio community 15 on windows 7, i must explicit add `import System`

why?
so, i have more than 100 web pages...i cant't modify all.

thank you!

on win10
[image]

on win7
[image]

just to be clear, i have the same solution on 2 differents envirorments, but on win10 is fine, on win7 i have the problem with reference.

**UPDATE**
thanks to all who tried to help me.
i solved creating a new Website solution, then i dragged all files (except for webconfig) and all references are fine.
i don't know why, but it's running.

Comment: Are the .vbproj file the same? If not add this in your .vbproj file `<Reference Include="System" />` under  `<ItemGroup> ....` or you can do that under References in Project -> Properties

Comment: yes, is the same solution...i don't understant what is the problem

Comment: ciao, grazie, purtroppo non trovo la voce che dici te..

Comment: English, people. This is an English-only site.

Comment: Ma sei su Visual Studio? Lo trovi si se segui i passaggi che ti ho detto

Comment: @jmcilhinney Hru? So, We are talking about anyone, it’s simply we are more confident in our language and there are simple comments, that, in my opinion someone takes them off in the evening :) have a nice day bro..

Comment: @elle0087 Do you see a "Project" menu? If so, does it have a "your_project_name Properties..." menu item (probably near the bottom of the menu)?

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj, I understand that you would rather write in your own language but that is irrelevant because this is an English-only site. Any comments you post should be on-topic and are therefore for everyone, not just you.

Comment: @Andrew Morton i see "web site" instead of "project"

Comment: @elle0087 Have you tried the "Add Reference..." menu item on the "Website" menu?

Comment: You may not have the same .NET Framework SDK and targeting pack version installed on the 2nd computer as you have on the 1st. If necessary, modify using Visual Studio Installer.

Comment: Are there any other errors after adding `import System`?

Comment: @Xingyu Zhao no, if i add import System all it's fine...i would like to understand what are the difference...

Comment: Make sure 'System.dll' has been added in the 'References' of project.

Comment: it's the same solution i open...System is not added, but on win 10 is used without problem.

Comment: Consider reporting your problem [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=problem).

Answer (score 2):

Open the *References* page of the project properties and you'll see a section showing the namespaces that are imported project-wide. The top half of the page is the referenced assemblies and the bottom half is the imported namespaces. You can add or remove imports by checking or unchecking items in that list. Anything checked in that list does not need to be imported at the file level.

Comment: so, System is not selected, but on win10 is working, on win7 no..

Comment: `System` IS selected if you actually look where I told you to. The Add Reference dialogue is completely irrelevant to this issue. As you don't know the difference between an assembly and a namespace, you should read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/12/referencing-assemblies-and-importing.html).

Comment: yes, i done, but the menu i saw is the 2nd pic i attached